# opencv motion tracker with identification

Tags: python, opencv, tracking, contour

Currently, the following script works perfectly fine, but I now want to give each rectangular bound box an identifier.

```
while True:
    # grab the current frame and initialize the occupied/unoccupied
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()

    if not grabbed:
        break

    # resize the frame, convert it to grayscale, and blur it
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)

    # if the first frame is None, initialize it
    if firstFrame is None:
        firstFrame = gray
        continue

    # compute the absolute difference between the current frame and
    # first frame
    frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(firstFrame, gray)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    # dilate the thresholded image to fill in holes, then find contours
    # on thresholded image
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),   cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:
        # if the contour is too small, ignore it

        if cv2.contourArea(c) < args["min_area"]:
            continue

        # compute the bounding box for the contour, draw it on the frame
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

For example, given the following image:

[image]

I want to be able to identify each of the four rectangular bounds as an object. (i.e. the leftmost is a bound box for the Queen of Diamonds card, and the rightmost is a bound box for the Ace of Hearts card)

Right now, I am stumped as to how I could possibly achieve this, and was wondering **if anyone could give me inspiration**.

Comment: There is a similar question on [answers.opencv.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150619072910/http://answers.opencv.org/question/53263/find-all-the-cards-that-are-above-and-their-center/)... Perhaps you can find something helpful there?

Comment: I am not sure the link you provided is pertaining to my query.. :/

Comment: I guess I didn't understand your question. What do you mean by "give each rectangular bound box an identifier"?

Comment: let's say there are two people walking in a video. i should be able to identify the first box as Person 1, the second box as Person 2

Comment: Oh, ok, you want to track multiple moving objects in successive frames of a video. So basically from the information acquired from previous frames, predict the position of each object in the current frame, and find the most likely match (in the first frame where you see the object, you need to make some educated guess). Can you tell the objects apart somehow? Or is everything you know just the position?

Comment: Yes! I only know the position.

Comment: Perhaps something like [optical flow](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html#gsc.tab=0) could help. Otherwise come up with a model for what constitutes valid motion. Once you know position of the same object in two consecutive frames, you can make a prediction of where it's likely to be in the next one. Then you for example pick the one that's closest to the predicted position.